# Keeping the indentation of the source document in the result document in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, indentation

I have been using Oxygen XML editor for my XSL transformations (Saxon-HE 9.8.0.8 on XSL v. 2 stylesheets) and the indentation of the source and result document have been the same: which is what I need.

When I run XSLT from command line (Saxon-HE 9.8.011J, Java version 1.8.0_161) I do not get the same result (the result document will have no indentation at all). Is there anything I can do to change this?

(`<xsl:output indent="yes"/>` would also indent my inline elements which is not what I need, `<xsl:strip-space elements/>` would delete some of the spaces between inline elements that are necessary).

Source:

```
    <chapter id="ch3">
    <title>Sed quam, quaes apiducius nit peror asperch icatiat</title>
            <section id="s1">
            <title>Et faccae sitiaessum res re dolorer errovitam,</title>
            <paragraph id="p6">
                <text>lorerit ab is arum dolore quaepudit exped magnate mpelestinus volupta</text>
            </paragraph>
            <paragraph id="p7">
                <text>lorerit ab is arum <span class="s1">dolore</span> <span class="s2">quaepudit</span> exped magnate mpelestinus volupta</text>
            </paragraph>
            <paragraph id="p12">
                <text>lorerit ab is arum dolore quaepudit exped magnate mpelestinus volupta</text>
            </paragraph>
    </section>
</chapter>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" >
            <xsl:for-each select="@*" >
                <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="paragraph">
        <xsl:element name="paragraph">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">p<xsl:number count="paragraph" from="chapter" level="any"></xsl:number>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Command line code

```
java -cp path\saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -t -s:path\source.xml -xsl:path\transformation.xsl -o:path\result.xml
```

Except the fact that the source code is in a specific DTD. When I remove the DTD mention at the beginning of the source code, the indentation remains the same, otherwise there is no indentation. What is the reason to this and how can I change it?

Thank you!
Maria
(I am quite a beginner)

Comment: I use the command `xmllint --format` to reindent my XML files. I try to delimit text nodes with the tags `<xsl:text>...</xsl:text>` in order to avoid adding or supressing spaces into the output whenever I fear any unsure behaviour around spaces.

Comment: Can you show us the exact command line and minimal but representative samples of XML, XSLT, output you want and the one you get? I don't think Saxon on the command line by default does any stripping of white space nor does it do any indentation so I am not sure why you see a difference between oXygen and Saxon on the command line.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my post, I think it is related to the DTD I am using but I cannot see how and why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If:

(a) you don't strip space from the input document

(b) your stylesheet copies all text nodes including whitespace text nodes to the result tree

(c) you don't indent with serialization

then the indentation of the result should be the same as the source.

If this isn't happening, then we need to see the details of exactly what you are doing. There are so many ways of getting whitespace wrong, it's impossible to know where you've gone wrong without seeing the detail.

(Incidentally you can use something like `suppress-indentation="p"` on `xsl:output` to get indentation above the paragraph level but not within paragraphs.)

Comment: Thank you! Could it be DTD related?

Comment: Yes, it could. The spec says: "elements that are defined in a DTD or a Schema to contain element-only content will have whitespace text nodes stripped, regardless of the xsl:strip-space and xsl:preserve-space declarations in the stylesheet."

Comment: Thank you. Do you think there is a way other than deleting the DTD mention in the source document to bypass this?